# Finite index proper subgroups of $Z[1/p]$

Tags: group-theory

I know how to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ has no finite index proper subgroups:

Let $H\leq\mathbb{Q}$ be a finite index subgroup. Let $x\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then $x+H=[\mathbb{Q}:H]\cdot(x/[\mathbb{Q}:H]+H)=H$ (by Lagrange's theorem). So $x\in H$, and thus $H=\mathbb{Q}$.

Now, what about finite index subgroups of $G=\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$? An analogous argument shows that if $[G:H]=p^n$ then $H=G$.

However, I still ask:

> Does $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ have finite index proper subgroups?

Comment: Yes it has subgroups of index $n$ for all $n>0$ that coprime to $p$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Is it just $n\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$?

Comment: @DerekHolt: Ah. I can see that this is indeed the case. Are you going to write it as an answer? If you so no, then I will write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you might go about obtaining these, which is almost certainly over the top.

Consider the standard short exact sequence:
$$0\rightarrow n\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \rightarrow 0,$$
and apply the exact functor $-\otimes\mathbb Z[1/p]$ to yield a short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow n\mathbb Z[1/p] \rightarrow \mathbb Z[1/p]\rightarrow \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \rightarrow 0,$$
after noting that $n$ coprime to $p$ gives $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\cong \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\otimes\mathbb Z[1/p]$.

To see that these are the *only* subgroups of finite index, take $H\leqslant\mathbb Z[1/p]$ of index $n$, and use your argument here to see that $n$ is necessarily coprime to $p$. Now it must contain $n\mathbb Z[1/p]$, since the quotient has exponent $n$. But $n\mathbb Z[1/p]$ also has index $n$ by the above. So $H=n\mathbb Z[1/p]$ as desired.