# Find all subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}[1/p]=\{a/p^n|\ a\in\Bbb{Z},n\ge 0\}$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

Let $N$ be a subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}[1/p]$. *WE FIRST ASSUME THAT* $1\in N$, then $\Bbb{Z}\subseteq N$. Let $n\ge 0$ be the largest non-negative integer (assuming exists) such that $1/p^n\in N\implies \frac{1}{p^n}\Bbb{Z}\subseteq N$.

Let $\frac{a}{p^m}\in N$ for some $p\not| a$. Then $\text{gcd}(p^m,a)=1\implies p^mx+ay=1\implies x+\frac{ay}{p^m}=\frac{1}{p^m}\implies \frac{1}{p^m}\in N$ (since $x\in \Bbb{Z}\subseteq N$). By our choice of $n$, $m\le n$, hence $\frac{a}{p^m}=\frac{ap^{n-m}}{p^n}\implies \frac{1}{p^n}\Bbb{Z}$. Therefore $N=\frac{1}{p^n}\Bbb{Z}$ in this case.

Now if there is no such largest $n$, then $\forall n\ge 0$, there is $a\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that $\frac{a}{p^n}\in N\implies \frac{1}{p^n}\in N\implies \frac{b}{p^n}\in N$  for all $b\in\Bbb{Z}, n\ge0$. Therefore $N=\Bbb{Z}[1/p]$.

But I cannot figure out what $N$ will be, when $1\notin N$? Can anyone help me finish complete the proof? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: All caps is yelling. Boldface and italics give emphasis. Any particular reason why you need to yell your assumption?

Comment: I think that one should start solving the problem with some reasonable hypothesis. For example, if $N<\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$, then either $N=a/p^n\mathbb{Z}$  or $N=q\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ for some fixed $a,n,q$.

Comment: For the finite index subgroups see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945162/finite-index-proper-subgroups-of-z1-p).